# Set name on apply results

Tags: r, apply, named

I am applying a function onto a `dataframe`.

But unlike `sapply` and its friends, `apply` hasn't got any `USE.NAME` argument to get a named list as returned object.

In this example, I'd like the `C` column to be the names of the returned list :

```
df = data.frame(A=c(1,2,3), B=c(9,5,7), C=c("A", "Z", "E"))
apply(df, 1, function(x){
  data.frame(xxx=as.numeric(x[1]) * as.numeric(x[2]))
})
# [[1]]
# xxx
# 1   9
# 
# [[2]]
# xxx
# 1  10
# 
# [[3]]
# xxx
# 1  21
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
apply(data.frame(df, row.names = df$C), 1, function(x){
  data.frame(xxx=as.numeric(x[1]) * as.numeric(x[2]))
})
#$A
#  xxx
#1   9
#
#$Z
#  xxx
#1  10
#
#$E
#  xxx
#1  21
```

Explanation: `apply` picks up `list` names from the dimnames of your corresponding `MARGIN` of your `data.frame` (in your case `MARGIN=1`, so `list` names will correspond to rownames).

Answer (score 2):

or use `setNames()` after you call apply:

```
 setNames(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
                         data.frame(xxx=as.numeric(x[1]) * as.numeric(x[2])) 
                       }), df$C)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the output should be the product of two columns in a `list`, then it can be done with `Reduce`

```
lst <- as.list(Reduce(`*`, df[-3]))
names(lst) <- df[,3]
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   transmute(xxx = A * B, C) %>% 
   split(.$C) %>% 
   map(~.x %>% 
      select(xxx))
```

Or with `nest`

```
df %>% 
   transmute(xxx = A * B, C) %>%
   nest(xxx)  %>% 
   mutate(data = set_names(data, C)) %>% 
   pull(data)
#$A
#   xxx
#1   9

#$Z
#   xxx
#2  10

#$E
#   xxx
#3  21
```

Comment: I wanted to know how to set names to a `apply` output, and I gave a reproducible example for testing. Your answer would be correct if my question was "how to multiply 2 columns and get the result as a named list". Still interesting though, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `apply`-function for this. You can just do:

```
 setNames(as.list(df[[1]] * df[[2]]), df[[3]])
```

The result:

```
$A
[1] 9

$Z
[1] 10

$E
[1] 21
```

Comment: Same comment as for Akrun, this is right about my example, but quite off-topic about my question. Thanks for answering though.